# Populating one array with elements of another array. Exceeding the length of the second array exception

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an assignment and I have come to a stumbling point where I get an exception that I am putting more elements in the array than in can hold. I have tried to make the array bigger, but it always goes beyond its bounds. Here is the code: [.NetFiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/ljKaB7).

The problematic part starts on line 43 and the exception is thrown on line 52:

```
 else
        {
            int x = 0;
            int SumValue = 0;
            int[] fibArray = new int[novArr.Length];

            for (x = 0; x < novArr.Length-1; x++)
            {
                if (x + 1 < novArr.Length)
                {
                    fibArray[SumValue] = novArr[x] - novArr[x + 1];
                }
                SumValue++;
            }
            Value = (fibArray.Max(element => Math.Abs(element)));
        }
```

Comment: Where did you get `value`? Because of `value`, that your increment in your `for` loop, may be bigger than the length of your array. Then `fibArray[value]` is the one that cause the crash.

Comment: Try debugging the code Index out of bounds means that you are usually trying to access an array position that is outside of the particular position and or counter in the for loop. perhaps it's in the novArr.Length - 1 line

Comment: @Larme, in the beginning of the block I have initialized it to zero. You can check the Fiddle. I figured it would take allot of space if I were to post the whole code here.

Comment: @Henry, no, `value` is not guaranteed to be initialized to zero before entering the `for (int x...)` loop. Remember the outer `for (int i...)` loop? (Also it is bad source code design to have one variable called "value" and another variable called "Value". This invites coding errors...)